# MFTF Run test not passing

Tags: magento2.4.3, unit-tests, mftf

I have installed Magento 2.4.3-p1 in the Ubuntu Apache server, Completed installation (fresh installation), and configuration for acceptance test case credentials. When I try to execute the MFTF it is showing an error few testcase.

1. AdminCreateAndEditBundleProductSettings
2. AdminCreateCreditMemoPartialRefundTest
3. AdminCreateOrderWithSimpleProductTest
4. StorefrontReorderAsGuestTest
5. StorefrontClearAllCompareProductsTestCest

My question is even when we execute the Mftf test case with fresh installation it is getting failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

> vendor/bin/mftf run:test StorefrontLoginRequiredFieldTest --remove
> --force

This helped me

Or it would be good to have an option for this (e.g. --skip-failed or --ignore-failing)